# How to set up shared iAd banners on xcode5?

Tags: xcode5

I have multiple viewControllers that I would like to run iAd. The iAd is setup correctly and is working on the first controller, but I m getting delegation errors.

---

```
adView.delegate = self;
[adView setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton for your ads.  Here's your .h:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface AEMIAd : NSObject <ADBannerViewDelegate>{
    ADBannerView *adView;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;

+(AEMIAd *)sharedAd;

@end
```

and your .m:

```
#import "AEMIAd.h"

static AEMIAd *sharedAd = nil;

@implementation AEMIAd

@synthesize adView;

- (id)init
{
    if (self)
    {

        // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.

        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)])
        {
            adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        } else adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];

        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0.0f, screenBounds.size.height-50.0f);
        adView.delegate = self;

    }

    return self;
}

-(BOOL)allowActionToRun
{
    return TRUE;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self.adView setHidden:NO];
    bannerIsVisible = YES;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.adView setHidden:YES];
    bannerIsVisible = NO;
}


+(AEMIAd *)sharedAd
{
    if (!sharedAd) sharedAd = [[self alloc] init];
    return sharedAd;
}
```

Lazy instantiation in each of your viewControllers:

```
-(ADBannerView *)adView
{
    if (!_adView) _adView = [[AEMIAd sharedAd] adView];
    return _adView;
}
```

and:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [adView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And that's that.